# how to call controller method from block file

Tags: controllers, system-config

I am calling a method written in controller file from a block file as shown in below code--

**BLOCK FILE**

```
class Assel_Sms_Block_Adminhtml_Sendpushmsg extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{


    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) 
    {
        $this->setElement($element);
        $buttonHtml = $this->_getAddRowButtonHtml($this->__('Send Push Message'));
        return $buttonHtml;
    }


  protected function _getAddRowButtonHtml($title)
  {

        $buttonBlock = $this->getElement()->getForm()->getParent()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button');

        $_websiteCode = $buttonBlock->getRequest()->getParam('website', null);

        $params = array();

        if(!empty($_websiteCode)) {
            $params['website'] = $_websiteCode;
        }

        // TODO: for real multi-store self-testing, the test button (and other configuration options) 
        // should probably be set to show in website. Currently they are not.
        $url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("*/pushmessage_sendpushmsg/sendpushnotification", $params);

        $buttonHtml = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                    ->setType('button')
                    ->setLabel($this->__($title))
                    ->setOnClick("window.location.href='".$url."'")
                    ->toHtml();

        return $buttonHtml;    
    }    
}
```

In above file code `$url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("*/pushmessage_sendpushmsg/sendpushnotification", $params);` is calling my controller method.but it is showing 404 page.

What I gonna do is I want to call above controller on click a button on system configuration page. as shown in below image-

[image]

Here is controller method--

```
<?php

class Assel_Sms_Pushmessage_SendpushmsgController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function sendpushnotificationAction() {


         $_helper = Mage::helper('sms');
         $_helper->log($_helper->__("Could not find required database tables"));
         return;
    }   

}
```

**EDITED--**

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
        <Assel_Sms>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </Assel_Sms>
   </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <sms>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Assel_Sms</module>
                    <frontName>sms</frontName>
                </args>
            </sms>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <sms>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Assel_Sms</module>
                    <frontName>sms</frontName>
                </args>
            </sms>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <sms>
                <class>Assel_Sms_Model</class>
            </sms>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <sms>
                <class>Assel_Sms_Block</class>
            </sms> 
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <sms>
                <class>Assel_Sms_Helper</class>
            </sms>
        </helpers>
        <rewrite>        
            <sms_customer_accountcontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/#]]></from> 
                <to>/sms/customer_account/</to> 
            </sms_customer_accountcontroller>
        </rewrite>
        <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsAfterOrder</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after>
                <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsAfterInvoice</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsAfterCreditmemo</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                <catalog_product_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsNotifyMe</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_save_after>
                <customer_register_success>
                    <observers>
                        <sms_customer_register_success>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsOnCustomerCreate</method>
                        </sms_customer_register_success>
                    </observers>
                </customer_register_success>
                <sales_order_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsOnOrderCancel</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_save_after>

                <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotpasswordpost>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsOnForgotPassword</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotpasswordpost>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: show your config.xml file

Comment: Hello Rajeev. see edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem is you are defining a new admin route for your module and the frontname for that route is `sms`. Hence your controller will be listened only when a url : `www.yourdomain.com/sms/pushmessage_sendpushmsg/sendpushnotification`

Instead you need to rewrite admin route in your module. The code for that shown below.

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <assel_sms before="Mage_Adminhtml">Assel_Sms</assel_sms>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here what you are doing is rewriting admin router, so that you can use the default admin router frontendname `admin`. Hope that makes sense

---

**Note 1 :** if you use this line of code.

```
$url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("sms/pushmessage_sendpushmsg/sendpushnotification", $params);
```

then you will be able to use your current admin router.

---

**Note 2 :** Best practice in Magento says, you should put all admin controller in `Adminhtml` directory in order to distinguish them from frontend controllers. So in order to do that, you need to do two changes.

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <assel_sms before="Mage_Adminhtml">Assel_Sms_Admintml</assel_sms>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

See the values inside `assel_sms` node. Now change your controller file accordingly.

File : `app\code\local\Assel\Sms\controllers\Adminhtml\Pushmessage\SendpushmsgController.php`

```
<?php

class Assel_Sms_Admihtml_Pushmessage_SendpushmsgController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function sendpushnotificationAction() {


         $_helper = Mage::helper('sms');
         $_helper->log($_helper->__("Could not find required database tables"));
         return;
    }   

}
```

Comment: hi Rajeev, thanks for reply. It worked. this time I am getting blanked page while I want to get same system configuration page with message on top. How can I do that.? Please ask if something is not clear.

Comment: you need to loadLayout();and renderLayout(); in your controller. It is a vast topic.

Comment: Actually I am following the Aschorder SMTP plugin. It is doing exactly what I want to do. It is calling controller file without calling any renderLayout() or  loadLayout(). and it is loading same configuration page.