# Controller Method is not being called from Block File

Tags: controllers, system-config

Controller is not being called from block file.

**Controller file**

```
<?php

class Assel_Sms_Adminhtml_PushmsgController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

   const PUSH_MSG_API_URL   = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
   const DB_TABLE= "app_users_cr";
   const REG_ID_DB_COLUMN = "gcm_regid"; 

   public function sendpushnotificationAction() 
   {
        try{

             $websiteModel = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'));
             $pushMessage = Mage::getStoreConfig('sms_cnfg/push_message/pushMessage', $websiteModel->getId());

             $registratoin_ids=$this->getRegistrationIds();

             $fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => $registratoin_ids,
                'data' => $pushMessage,
             );

             $headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
             );
             // Open connection
             $ch = curl_init();

             // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, PUSH_MSG_API_URL);

             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

             // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

            // Execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }

             $this->_redirectReferer();
    }

    public function getRegistrationIdsAction()
    {
            $connectionRead = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
            //$query="SELECT". REG_ID_DB_COLUMN." FROM ".DB_TABLE."";
            $query="SELECT gcm_regid FROM app_users_cr";
            $registrationIds= $connectionRead->fetchAll($query);
            print_r($registrationIds);
    }
}
```

**Block file**

```
<?php


class Assel_Sms_Block_Adminhtml_Pushmsg extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{


    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) 
    {
        $this->setElement($element);
        $buttonHtml = $this->_getAddRowButtonHtml($this->__('Send Push Message'));
        return $buttonHtml;
    }


  protected function _getAddRowButtonHtml($title)
  {

        $buttonBlock = $this->getElement()->getForm()->getParent()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button');

        $_websiteCode = $buttonBlock->getRequest()->getParam('website', null);

        $params = array();

        if(!empty($_websiteCode)) {
            $params['website'] = $_websiteCode;
        }

        // TODO: for real multi-store self-testing, the test button (and other configuration options) 
        // should probably be set to show in website. Currently they are not.
        $url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("*/pushmsg/sendpushnotification", $params);

        $buttonHtml = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                    ->setType('button')
                    ->setLabel($this->__($title))
                    ->setOnClick("window.location.href='".$url."'")
                    ->toHtml();

        return $buttonHtml;    
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
        <Assel_Sms>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </Assel_Sms>
   </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <assel_sms before="Mage_Adminhtml">Assel_Sms</assel_sms>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <sms>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Assel_Sms</module>
                    <frontName>sms</frontName>
                </args>
            </sms>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <sms>
                <class>Assel_Sms_Model</class>
            </sms>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <sms>
                <class>Assel_Sms_Block</class>
            </sms> 
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <sms>
                <class>Assel_Sms_Helper</class>
            </sms>
        </helpers>
        <rewrite>        
            <sms_customer_accountcontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/#]]></from> 
                <to>/sms/customer_account/</to> 
            </sms_customer_accountcontroller>
        </rewrite>
        <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsAfterOrder</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after>
                <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsAfterInvoice</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsAfterCreditmemo</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                <catalog_product_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsNotifyMe</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_save_after>
                <customer_register_success>
                    <observers>
                        <sms_customer_register_success>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsOnCustomerCreate</method>
                        </sms_customer_register_success>
                    </observers>
                </customer_register_success>
                <sales_order_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsOnOrderCancel</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_save_after>

                <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotpasswordpost>
                    <observers>
                        <sms>
                            <class>sms/observer</class>
                            <method>sendSmsOnForgotPassword</method>
                        </sms>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotpasswordpost>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

controller method **sendpushnotification** not being called from block file. It is showing 404 page error.

Comment: Did you try like this: Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/pushmsg/sendpushnotification", $params); (replacing the * with adminhtml) ?

Comment: Hi Rajeev, It may be but I just refreshed cache it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the same question again. I have **[already given a solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98749/3535)** to your previous question. I also give you sufficient explanation on how and why it didn't work.

Here in this case, your rewrite node value is wrong. It should be

```
<assel_sms before="Mage_Adminhtml">Assel_Sms_Adminhtml</assel_sms>
```

After made change, please clear cache and reload page again.